# Intro to Python: Creating a function that tests the validity of 'months'

Tags: python, variables, boolean

I have to say thank you in advance to whomever is helping me out here, I recently started learning python a fews days ago and a current problem set we are working on has been quite confusing.

I think it has to do with a fundamental misunderstanding of mine on how **parameters** are assigned within a **function**.

As I have briefly mentioned in title, I am being tasked with creating a function `is_months_valid(months)`

This is what I have done so far, brace yourselves:

```
def is_valid_month(month):
    month = int
    if month <= 0:
    month == False
    print('this is not a valid month')
    if month >12:
    month = False 
    print('this is not a valid month')
    return month
```

As you can see what I am trying to do here is create an integer range from 1 to 12 where 'months' is a valid date.

The issue that I have been encountering is this:

```
'<=' not supported between instances of 'type' and 'int'
```

I.e a type error, and I think that my issue is that I am having trouble defining my parameter 'months' as an integer that can take any value. And this value, when run through my program presents me with a valid month or a print statement that says that

```
'this isnt a valid month'
```

Again, I am not sure how my code appears to anyone outside my perspective but I would appreciate any and all feedback on it.

Thank you

EDIT: Thank you guys my little frankenstein code finally works, for some reason I was under the assumption that in order to have my parameter (month) take any integer value I wanted, I needed to define it as an 'int.'

I know that stackoverflow isnt "help a student with his cs homework.com" but thank you all for your feedback regarding my indentation, the rules of python, and the guidance in the right direction. Coding is something that I want to improve on and hopefully become literate in.

- Thank you

Comment: What is this `month = int` supposed to do? (clue: this is why you're having a problem)

Comment: The indentation of your code in incorrect and indentation is very significant in Python and your code won't work if it is wrong.

Comment: In case you're coming from another more strict language than Python, variables are dynamically typed in Python. That means that you do not have to "set" the type of them before assigning values to them.

Comment: Just delete the line `month = int`.  Presumably this is meant to somehow indicate that `month` is an `int`, or should be an `int`.  It doesn't.  It assigns the class `int` to the variable `month`, discarding the value that was passed to the function.  After that, `month` is a class, which isn't going to be of much use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant that!

```
def is_valid_month(month):
    if month <= 0:
        month = False
        print('this is not a valid month')
    elif month >12:
        month = False 
        print('this is not a valid month')
    else:month=True

    return month
```